# SAS expand lag1() to some columns of a dataset

Tags: sas

I would like to apply the function lag1() to some columns of a dataset.

I have a dataset with n columns:

```
Date         Col1   Col2   Col3   ...  Coln
01/01/2000    10     5      5     ...   3
01/02/2000     7    10      5     ...   1
01/03/2000     9     2      8     ...   1
01/04/2000     3     5      4     ...   8
```

I would like to get:

```
Date         Col1   Col2   Col3   ...  Coln
01/01/2000     .     .      .     ...   .
01/02/2000    -3     5      0     ...  -2
01/03/2000     2    -8      3     ...   0
01/04/2000    -6     3     -4     ...   7
```

I did it one by one using this command:

```
data test_tab;
   set mydata;
   test=Col2-lag1(col2);
run;
```

but I would like to get it for all columns but the first, given that there are some hundreds of columns.
What do you suggest?
Thank you!

Comment: Refactor your data structure is the first option, if you're in a Long format it's adding two to three lines for the by group processing. Otherwise, PROC EXPAND + macro if you have SAS/ETS.

Answer (score 2):

Specify a variable based array for the variables you want to 'differate' and loop over the elements computing the lagged difference with the `DIF` function.

Example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array x x2-x10 x20-x89 x91-x100;
  do _i_ = 1 to dim(x);
    x(_i_) = dif(x(_i_));
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Hi! I tried with this code. I get a table containing the original dataset and the xn additional columns, but the new columns are empty. Could you help me?

Comment: Create a new question.  Make sure you show the data (either a small portion or some made up example data) used, the code you ran, the messages shown in the log. Also include result you want and the result you got.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is as nicely formatted as you posted, you can do this with some variable selection shortcuts and arrays. The shortcut `col2--coln` will select all variables between `col2` and `coln` inclusive.

```
data test_ab;
    set mydata;
    array var[*] col2--coln;

    do i = 1 to dim(var);
        var[i] = var[i] - lag(var[i]);
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I tried with this, but I get the following error: test_ab may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there
         were 0 observations and 169 variables.

Comment: Where does the error occur? If there are any character columns in-between your columns of interest it could cause this error.